# Study the stability of the following ODE: $u'=u(1-u)-\alpha$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

Given that $\alpha$ is real, I'm being asked to give a basic analysis for this nonlinear ODE.  However the problem is that I'm having trouble understanding how to pick the conditions we need to study for alpha before determining stability, instability or semi stability?  Can someone help me understand this better?

Comment: This is a Riccati equation. Just change the variables $u=\frac{y'}{y}$.

Comment: Do not solve the differential equation but plot the graph of $x\mapsto x(1-x)-\alpha$ and deduce the phase diagram. For example, if $\alpha=3/16$ the fixed points are $1/4$ (unstable) and $3/4$ (stable).